# How did the transdimensional Edo god (Edo lord) come to be the overseer of the Edo?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

I guess it's sort of like the way that Q had a vested interest in humanity in general---and Picard's Enterprise in particular. Q wasn't really an overseer, though. He visited the Enterprise mainly to screw around with people and play games. The Edo god clearly desired the Edo as its own---it called one Edo "my child," and so on ("Justice").

Is there anything anywhere which tells us how or why this bizarre relationship started?

Answer (score 7):

The Edo's "God" actually seems to be a ship or a vessel (described by Maurice Hurley in the [Unathorised Voyages](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0316329576) as a "*machine-god*") which contains a number of transdimensional beings, a race whose own dimension intrudes into our own inside a star cluster which happens to contain the [Edo world](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Rubicun_III).

Within the episode, Data offers us some pretty conclusive ideas about the nature of the Edo's deity:

> **DATA :** *But when they were probing my thoughts, Captain, **I could feel that whatever they are now, they once existed in this dimension,
>   just as we do.** Perhaps also in the same kind of "flesh and blood"
>   form. Since then, however, they have evolved considerably further.
>   Their present existence in mixed dimensions no doubt has advantages we
>   do not understand...*
>
> **PICARD :** *Then, in their earlier flesh and blood existence they could have once shared our kind of values.*
>
> **DATA :** *The Edo share them, sir.*
>
> **PICARD :** ***Why would advanced things like that feel obliged to protect the Edo?***
>
> **DATA :** *Perhaps because the Edo are a child-race by comparison. **Possibly a race which the life forms over there "planted" here much as
>   we now plant human colonies on Class-M planets.***

Assuming he's right, that would certainly explain the **parental nature** of the Edo's relationship with their god.

Answer (score 1):

The Memory Alpha pages on ["Justice"](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Justice_(episode)), [the Edo](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Edo), [the Edo God](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Edo_God), and [Rubicun III](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Rubicun_III) — along with the Memory Beta pages on ["Justice"](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Justice) and [the Edo](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Edo) (There's no Memory Beta page on the Edo God or Rubicon III) are all completely silent on the history of the Edo and their god.  It thus appears that there are no licensed (i.e., non-fanfiction) works in existence that answer your question.