# In season 1 episode 7 "justice" of Star Trek TNG do we ever learn what the entities that the Edo call god really are?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, star-trek-data, star-trek-eu

Is there anything in canon that teaches us what the entities orbiting the planet are, their capabilities, where they come from, etc.?

I am happy to accept responses based on the expanded universe (EU).

Comment: Related, not dupe; http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/70739/how-did-the-transdimensional-edo-god-edo-lord-come-to-be-the-overseer-of-the-e

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, the answer is **no**.

- They weren't mentioned in any future TV episode, nor in any of the feature films.
- I've done a quick search through all 1207 Star Trek novels and although there are fleeting mentions to the Edo and their God (referred to in the Star Trek Companion as the "EdoLord"), there don't appear to be any novels which explore this relationship in any greater detail.
- They aren't mentioned in any of the classic TNG comics.
- They aren't mentioned in any of the new "ongoing" Trek comics.

Comment: How do you search through all of the Star Trek Novels? Is there a site for that? @Richard

Comment: @JMFB - [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/) + [Quality Check Plugin](http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=125428) + [Every Star Trek book in epub format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Star_Trek_novels) = Result

Comment: awesome thanks. I've never heard of Calibre before. But I'll definitely check it out when I get back home. I'm in NYC for five days. Did you pay/download every star trek book individually?

Comment: @JMFB - Yes, because downloading them from a torrent site would be morally wrong.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that. I don't really use a torrent client. I was just wondering if there was a resource check without having to purchase them all individually. I imagine that there are hundreds of ST novels.

Comment: @JMFB - There are a little over 1200 licensed novels and tie-in books. As far as I'm aware, there are no online resources that would allow you to check them all for content. [Memory Beta](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Main_Page) is probably as close as you're gonna get but it's notoriously inaccurate and incomplete.